# Class 'Mpociot\ApiDoc\ApiDocGeneratorServiceProvider' not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, laravel-5.5

I am currently working on L5.5 and there for generating api docs I have installed [this](https://github.com/mpociot/laravel-apidoc-generator) package, now  I don't need that package I decided to uninstall it but while doing uninstalling I got this error.

```
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover


  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]          
  Class 'Mpociot\ApiDoc\ApiDocGeneratorServiceProvider' not found  


Script @php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
```

I checked on repo's issue and on net but haven't got satisfying answer.

I uninstalled this repo by doing following this

remove repo from `composer.json` and then I ran the command `composer update`.

Any idea why it is appearing and how to fix this error??

Thank you for your efforts :)

I have removed the mentioned file still I am getting this error [image]

Comment: check your config/app.php if it contains something like: `Mpociot\ApiDoc\ApiDocGeneratorServiceProvider::class,` this seems to be a loaded Service Class

Comment: no I have removed  that class to from providers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to `config/app.php` and make sure you removed

```
Mpociot\ApiDoc\ApiDocGeneratorServiceProvider::class
```

from this. Now run:

```
php artisan clear-compiled
```

and

```
php artisan config:clear
```

to make sure you are not using any cache. After that there shouldn't be any problems

**NOTE**

if you are getting this issue even after this then go to `bootstrap/cache/config.php` as mentioned by Marcin Nabiałek down there in comments and in that delete `Mpociot\ApiDoc\ApiDocGeneratorServiceProvider::class` from the array of `providers` after that rerun the above three commands.

Comment: thank you for the reply I did that and as you can see I have updated my question with the image the issue still persists.

Comment: So go to `bootstrap/cache` directory and remove `compiled.php` file. Run also `composer dump-autoload` just in case and try again.

Comment: wow you just solved my problem! thanks a tonne you have saved my day :)

Comment: I found it in bootstrap/cache/config.php I'm editing your answer

Comment: You mean `bootstrap/cache/config.php` file? Normally `php artisan config:clear` should work

Comment: yeah I got it there no in my case php artisan config:clear was throwing the same error I had to go there and manually deleted that after I'm back on the track! :)